# Trying to use IFTTT to send string to IoT module

Tags: http, tcp, iot, ifttt

Currently I am trying to use IFTTT to connect my google assistant to an IoT device I made.  The google assistant command is triggering a webhook to send the string and I have the IP address and port that it should be able to communicate to.  I have tried setting the URL to "http://:" (Itried it with https as well), but it is saying the request is timing out.  I know the IoT module works since it has worked with a .jar file that sent the data when provided with an IP address and port number.  Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.